# What is the name or author of this tangrams-like packing puzzle?

Tags: geometry, puzzle-identification, packing

Does someone knows the name of this packing puzzle, or its inventor?

The goal is to repack the shapes into the square with the additional red square.

It is an easy puzzle but the construction is interesting.

[image: packing puzzle]

Comment: It seems like something Vladimir Krasnoukhov could have designed. The only source my web searches have uncovered is [etsy](https://www.etsy.com/listing/622307941/), but that shows no further info about it.

Comment: Or Henry Dudeney or Sam Lloyd...

Comment: Thank you, Jaap, this is a useful lead.

Answer (score 4):

The puzzle is called "Magic Square (Philos)", by the Dutch-Italian game designer Niek Neuwahl.

(from https://wittingen-puzzels.jimdofree.com/puzzles/2d-assemble-puzzles/)

Also, Creative Crafthouse (and possibly others) has it under the name "The Impossible No Fit Puzzle." or "No Fit" puzzle.

(https://www.creativecrafthouse.com/no-fit-puzzle-how-can-this-be-premium-version-in-cast-acrylic.html)